# Aurelia CLI with Require loading styles before main.js

Tags: css, requirejs, aurelia

I have a problem...
I have an Aurelia pplication where I would like to load styles from Index.html  instead of app.html.

Why?

Because when the application starts, there is a slight timespan before styles are loaded where user can see unstyled application.
As I am loading all the styles in app.html, the main.js executes before, and it loads all the plugins that takes some time.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use a standard `link` element to link to the css file in `index.html`. This stylesheet will not be bundled with your application bundle, and it can't be as you need access to it before your bundle file(s) is/are parsed.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />
```

You can add a gulp task to copy this file at build time, as the Aurelia CLI is built on gulp tasks.